# error "Microsoft Outlook got an error: Can’t make class calendar event." number -2710 from calendar event to class

Tags: outlook, applescript, osx-mavericks

I am trying to create a new event using apple scrip in outlook but I don't know why this error is coming.

```
--read source from the file

set theFile to "/Users/eclit/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Data Records/Template/MeetingTemplate.html"
open for access theFile
set fileContents to (read theFile)
close access theFile

on replaceText(find, replace, subject)
    set prevTIDs to text item delimiters of AppleScript
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to find
    set subject to text items of subject

    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to replace
    set subject to "" & subject
    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to prevTIDs

    return subject
end replaceText

on categoryForName(_categoryName)
    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        try
            return category _categoryName
        on error
            try
                -- Getting by name doesn't always work.
                repeat with _category in categories
                    if _category's name is _categoryName then return _category
                end repeat
            end try
            make new category with properties {name:_categoryName}
        end try
        return category _categoryName
    end tell
end categoryForName



tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    set currentTime to current date

    set theCategory to my categoryForName("Work")
    set newEvent to make new calendar event with properties {subject:"Dial In : +442034333797,  Conference code: 4754632380", start time:currentTime, end time:(currentTime + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1)), content:fileContents}
    open newEvent

end tell
```

in `fileContents` I am getting the data but event is not creating.

Comment: What exactly is in fileContents? Can you post more of your code?

Comment: That snippet is working for me, if i set currentTime to (the current date) and fileContents to "anything", on 10.7

Comment: I am reading the file template for mail body and that's filecontain.

Comment: Can you tell me me where i can find this kinda error code number?

Comment: I'm still not clear about this, it's likely in the fileContents or the currentTime variables, if we can see more of the preceding code we can better help you. Also how are you running this, from with in AppleScript Editor or something else? Also, i've idea about that error code sorry.

Comment: I have updated the complete script so can you tell me whats wrong!!

Comment: I got the error as "set theCategory to my categoryForName("Work")" line is causing the error after outlook update from 14.0 to 14.1.3

Comment: Ta, your whole script is working for me when i point it at my own html (as my outlook does not have that file). I'm on 10.7.5 but my Outlook is 14.3.6. Maybe this could be a mavericks issue? Not sure, perhaps some one on it could test too? Again to ask, are you running this direct from AppleScript Editor?

Comment: Yes, issue fixed after remove the categoryforname

Comment: @adamh: the whole script works for me on Mavericks (10.9.1, Outlook 14.3.9), either from within the AppleScript editor or when exported as an app.

Comment: Could it be something that Outlook does not like in your HTML? (Perhaps more strict checks in a newer version of Outlook?)

Comment: I don't know because this was working with 14.0 but after update it was not working, can you tell me how to set the category of email here using apple script